# Mobile redirect using htaccess or other option

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile

I have a website built with the Expression Engine CMS and it has been working fine for 2 years now.  I just had a static mobile site built (html-based) and we added a redirect script to the home page that is working fine also.  So, if a mobile users tries to access the home page, the users is correctly redirected to the mobile site -- no issue here.

Problem is that we use discreet pages from the site in facebook, google adwords and other sources so we need the redirect to work not just for the home page but for about 10 other pages that we drive users to.

EE allows the template pages to be edited and I have modified the EE template for pages like about-us that are single pages from a single EE category and this is working fine also.  But I am having the issue with the redirect in the case of an EE category with multiple discreet pages.  In this case there is only a single page in EE template to put the redirect script so a mobile device will always get redirected to the same page in the category regardless of which page was actually chosen.

Can we use an htacess redirect to solve this issue somehow?  It would need to look at the page being called and redirect to a specific mobile page? Is there a php or other script option to solve this issue.

Goal is that we need for mobile devices to be directed to a specific page in the situation where we can only add redirect script at the category level in EE.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getClientOS()
    {
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $os_platform = "Unknown OS Platform";

        $os_array = array (
            '/windows nt 6.2/i' => 'Windows 8',
            '/windows nt 6.1/i' => 'Windows 7',
            '/windows nt 6.0/i' => 'Windows Vista',
            '/windows nt 5.2/i' => 'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
            '/windows nt 5.1/i' => 'Windows XP',
            '/windows xp/i' => 'Windows XP',
            '/windows nt 5.0/i' => 'Windows 2000',
            '/windows me/i' => 'Windows ME',
            '/win98/i' => 'Windows 98',
            '/win95/i' => 'Windows 95',
            '/win16/i' => 'Windows 3.11',
            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' => 'Mac OS X',
            '/mac_powerpc/i' => 'Mac OS 9',
            '/linux/i' => 'Linux',
            '/ubuntu/i' => 'Ubuntu',
            '/iphone/i' => 'iPhone',
            '/ipod/i' => 'iPod',
            '/ipad/i' => 'iPad',
            '/android/i' => 'Android',
            '/blackberry/i' => 'BlackBerry',
            '/webos/i' => 'Mobile'
        );
```

This function would return you the value(Desktop/Mobile) that which OS is being used by your client, you can use this function on the top of your page and redirect to the specific page you have made for mobile device and vice versa. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but we already have php code working that detects mobile and redirects to the mobile site.  Issue is as follows.  In EE we have a category like "Treatment Programs" and there are say 10 pages in this category, call them Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, etc.  From an EE perspective all these pages use the same page template.  It is at the template level where redirect code can be added since you can't access specific pages in EE.  So, the problem is that if a user requests Page 3 as the initial call we cannot redirect to a specific mobile page because the redirect code is at the template level.